# Phone - How to do setup to create phonegap application

Tags: android, node.js, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I followed lot of links but not able to run my application.

Steps I followed

1. Installed node.js.
2. downloaded eclipse juno.
3. Installed ADK plugin with `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`.
4. Installed platforms and other thing mentioned in below pictures.
   [image]
5. I installed phongap by using `npm install -g phonegap` command.
6. I am trying to create a new phonegap app by `phonegap create my-app` but its giving error

> Error: Cannot find module 'cordova-common'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>       at require (module.js:385:17)

The way I followed is correct or not? Please give me any link to create new phonegap application from setting required sertup.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

try to update Cordova's version to the latest version:

CLI:

```
sudo npm update -g cordova
```

It fixed my issue with adding/building ios platform (same error)